# Insert Building Block in footer using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to insert a building block into footer of a word document, but when I use the following code I get an error:

```
ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate. _
BuildingBlockEntries("Footer Test").Insert Where:=.Section.Footers(1).Range, RichText:= _
True
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: What is the error? If it's "Expected: identifier or bracketed expression", you need to uncomment the continuation lines.

Comment: I had it uncommented in the code, but commented it so I can run the rest of the error.

Comment: The error is: Compile Error: Invalid or unqualified reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Invalid or unqualified reference" means that you've used a deference operator ('.') without an object for it to deference, specifically `.Section`. That's pretty much the compiler's way of telling you ".Section of what?" The only time you should have a bare '.' operator is inside of a `With` block.  I can't tell what you are trying to operate on much better than the compiler can with only the one line of code to work with, but it should likely be something like...

```
ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate. _
    BuildingBlockEntries("Footer Test").Insert _
        Where:=ActiveDocument.Sections(x).Footers(1).Range, _
        RichText:= True
```

...where `x` is the appropriate `Section`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Comintern. If I want the content on the first page in the footer, what do I have to replace the x by?

Comment: @VBAPete - I would presume 1, but wouldn't be able to know without seeing the document and the rest of the code.